# Length of an extender in the iteration tree game is less than the support of the last extender in the respective premouse

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory

I am studying iteration trees from the "An Outline of Inner Model Theory" article in the handbook and I'm struggling with a bit of the material. It's on the first paragraph of page $1614$.

At this point we are defining the $\mathcal{G}_k(\mathcal{M}, \theta)$ game and suppose we are at stage $\alpha+1$ and suppose $I$ chooses an extender $F_\alpha$ from the $\mathcal{M}_\alpha$ sequence such that $\text{lh}(F_\xi) < \text{lh}(F_\alpha)$ for every $\xi<\alpha$. And let $\beta\le\alpha$ be least such that $\text{crit}(F_\alpha)<\nu(F_\beta)$ Then the article proceeds to show that there exists a (largest) $\gamma$ such that $\text{lh}(F_\beta) \le \gamma$, and $F_\alpha$ is a pre-extender over $\mathcal{C}_0(\mathcal{J}^{\mathcal{M}_\beta}_\gamma)$. Also for notational conveniece let $\kappa = \text{crit}(F_\alpha)$ and $\nu = \nu(\mathcal{J}^{\mathcal{M}_\beta}_\gamma)$

The only step of the proof I don't understand is when we want to prove that $F_\alpha$ is a pre-extender over $\mathcal{C}_0(\mathcal{J}^{\mathcal{M}_\beta}_\gamma)$ for $\gamma$ such that $\mathcal{J}^{\mathcal{M}_\beta}_\gamma$ is type $III$ and $\text{lh}(F_\beta)<\gamma$ and we already know that $F_\alpha$ is a pre-extender over $\mathcal{J}^{\mathcal{M}_\beta}_\gamma$. It seems to me that since $\nu$ is the largest cardinal of $\mathcal{J}^{\mathcal{M}_\beta}_\gamma$, the article infers that $\text{lh}(F_\beta) \le \nu$ and so $\kappa < \nu$ and by the agreement condition and acceptability, we are done. But the step I don't understand is the inference: $\text{lh}(F_\beta) \le \nu$.

The only information I can see right now is that: $\text{lh}(F_\beta)$ is a cardinal of $\mathcal{M}_\alpha$, and if we had $\text{lh}(F_\beta)$ is also a cardinal of $\mathcal{M}_\beta$, then the inference would follow, because $\nu$ is the largest cardinal in $\mathcal{J}^{\mathcal{M}_\beta}_\gamma$. But then again, since we may choose $F_\beta$ anywhere in the extender sequence of $\mathcal{M}_\beta$, there is no obvious reason for $\text{lh}(F_\beta)$ to be a cardinal in $\mathcal{J}^{\mathcal{M}_\beta}_\gamma$ as far as I can see.

How can we justify the inference then?
Sorry for the long post, thanks for reading.

Comment: What is a premouse ? An ancestor of a mouse ?

Comment: In some weird and techincal sense, yes. :D But on a more serious note, it is a set theoretical structure used to construct canonical inner models for large cardinals as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Apologies for the floor-level of my humor.

Comment: You're welcome. I actually think it was a bit funny. :)

Comment: You might want to ask this over on MathOverflow (or more properly, perhaps, migrate it there); it seems a good fit there, and there are several set theorists who I think frequent that site more regularly than this one.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, since my question is about the definition of iteration games, I think it's best if I wait at least a day or two before doing that. Maybe I am missing something obvious here. Thanks for the suggestion though, I'll definitely try to migrate/repost after a few days or maybe after a bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re correct; the phrase (in first paragraph page 1614) "Thus if $\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)<\gamma$, then $\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)\leq\nu$" is false. But the overall thing is still fine, i.e. $\kappa<\nu$.

Edit: Why $\kappa<\nu$: Steel says it's clear if $\beta=\alpha$, and so assumes $\beta<\alpha$. But it seems to me that some of the same thoughts are relevant in the $\beta=\alpha$ case. So I won't assume $\beta<\alpha$. We are assuming that $\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)<\gamma$.  Write $N|\xi$ for the initial segment of premouse $N$ of ordinal height $\xi$, retaining the extender indexed at $\xi$, if there is one, and $N||\xi$ for its passivization, i.e. removing the extender indexed at $\xi$.

Suppose first that $\beta=\alpha$. Then $\kappa=\mathrm{crit}(F_\beta)$ and $(\kappa^+)^{M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)}\leq\nu(F_\beta)<\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)$. But note that  by choice of $\gamma$ (and acceptability etc), we have $(\kappa^+)^{M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\gamma}=(\kappa^+)^{M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)}$, so $(\kappa^+)^{M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\gamma}<\gamma$, and since $\nu$ is  the largest cardinal of $M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\gamma$ (as we are assuming the latter is type 3), therefore $(\kappa^+)^{M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\gamma}\leq\nu$, so $\kappa<\nu$.

Now suppose instead that $\beta<\alpha$. Then it is similar: We have $\kappa<\nu(F_\beta)<\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)$ and $M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta||\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)=M^{\mathcal{T}}_\alpha|\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)$ and $\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)$ is a cardinal in $M^{\mathcal{T}}_\alpha$.
So $(\kappa^+)^{M^{\mathcal{T}}_\alpha|\mathrm{lh}(F_\alpha)}=(\kappa^+)^{M^{\mathcal{T}}_\alpha}=(\kappa^+)^{M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)}$ and the models $M^{\mathcal{T}}_\alpha$ and $M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta$ agree strictly below this ordinal. (In general it can be that $\kappa$ is the largest cardinal of $M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)$ (if $F_\beta$ is type 2); in this case $(\kappa^+)^{M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)}$ means $\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)$, and the agreement stops right at that point. But then $M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)$ projects to $\kappa$, so $\gamma=\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)$ in this case, contrary to our assumption that $\gamma>\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)$.) But now by choice of $\gamma$ and like before, (let)
$\kappa_+=(\kappa^+)^{M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)}=(\kappa^+)^{M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\gamma}$, and $\kappa_+\leq\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)<\gamma$, so like before,  $\kappa_+\leq\nu$.

(Recall that in "Outline of IMT", premice are all "below superstrong"; when one modified this to allow superstrong extenders on the sequence, some things above must be modified a little bit.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know strictly speaking this wasn't part of my question, but can you please explain why $\kappa<\nu$?

Comment: @ShervinSorouri No problem. I added the explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded answer! Really appreciate it. I have two questions though: $1)$ I don't understand the "$M_\beta^\mathcal{T}|\text{lh}(F_\beta)$ projects onto $\kappa$" bit, and also how does it give $\gamma = |\text{lh}(F_\beta)$? Can you please elaborate on it? And $2)$ I haven't encountered the assumption of working under a superstrong thus far, have we implicitly assumed and used it in our arguments, or is this a byproduct of using short extenders?

Comment: With "projects to $\kappa$" it should really have said "projects $\leq\kappa$"; I'll change that. This basically means "its projectum is $\leq\kappa$", which however might be vague in meaning, depending on which projectum one is talking about. If $N$ is a fully sound premouse, then "$N$ projects $\leq\kappa$" presumably means the $\omega$th projectum of $N$ is $\leq\kappa$. But in this case it doesn't matter, as if $N$ is any active premouse and $\gamma$ is its largest cardinal then $\rho_1^N\leq\gamma$. This is because there is a surjection $\pi:\nu^N\to\mathrm{OR}^N$ coded by $F^N$.

Comment: So (with notation as in the original question) if $\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)<\mathrm{OR}(M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta)$ but $\kappa$ is the largest cardinal of $M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)$ then $\rho_1(M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta))\leq\kappa$, so there is a new subset of $\kappa$ in $\mathcal{J}(M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta))$, which is not measured by $E=E^{\mathcal{T}}_\alpha$, since $\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)$ is a cardinal in $M^{\mathcal{T}}_\alpha$. So $M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta|\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)$ is the largest segment of $M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta$ measured by $E$.

Comment: Therefore $\gamma=\mathrm{lh}(F_\beta)$ in this case. Re (2) superstrongness, it's not stated that way in "Outline" (or FSIT); it's just part of the definition of "premouse" (or maybe "extender", I forget) that if $N$ is an active premouse and $F=F^N$ then $i_F(\kappa)>\mathrm{OR}^N$ where $\kappa=\mathrm{crit}(F)$. But if one drops that requirement and allows $i_F(\kappa)=$ the largest cardinal of $\mathrm{N}$, then things still work similarly, but with (usually) small changes. This also makes it more parallel to the usual theory of premice with Jensen (or $\lambda$-) indexing.

Comment: A small difference that comes up (when allowing superstrong) is that one can have $E^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta$ superstrong and $\mathrm{OR}(M^{\mathcal{T}}_{\beta+1})=\mathrm{lh}(E^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta)$ (where $\mathrm{lh}(E^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta)$ still denotes the index of the extender, which is still the cardinal successor of its natural length in its ultrapower). In this case $M^{\mathcal{T}}_{\beta+1}$ is active type 2, and then $\mathrm{lh}(E^{\mathcal{T}}_{\beta+1})=\mathrm{lh}(E^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta)$.

Comment: The biggest difference that I'm aware of allowing superstrong extenders comes up in the proof of Dodd-solidity (but this doesn't come up in Outline/FSIT).

Comment: Oh I see. That's a nice use of the projectum! And the part related to the superstrong case is a bit vague to me right now, and I think I'll have to come back to it further down the line I guess. Thanks for the detailed explanation!